# remove caching from breadcrumbs section

Tags: cache

our product page has full page caching, however, our breadcrumbs shouldn't be cached but they are.  is there a way around this?  How so?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will find your answer in the following post thats why i am writing it as an answer. Give it a try:

[disabling caching for some files in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499394/disable-caching-for-some-files-in-magento)